# hp dl580 g5 diag error

Tags: hard-drive, diagnostic

server disk access is slow, and running insight diagnostics reports this error:

Error: 640003 DST Error

Error: 640006: The Read and/or Write HARD error rate is above threshold
This drive has experienced/recorded error conditions reported by diagnosis and requires replacement"

Answer (score 2):

replace the drive

Comment: yes, do what dyasny says.

Comment: Call support: 800-334-5144   or Open a case online: http://welcome.hp.com/country/us/en/contact/supportcase1.html (Make sure you fill out the Model # of the server and the failed drive, and the serial of the server, and the HD if you know it).